# Chrome Cast Custom ActionBar Icon

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Can anyone help to implement custom drawables for  actionbar media router icon. I already have two custom drawable xmls for connecting and connected states. But i don't know how to apply those drawables to the cast icon in the actionbar. Any help is much appreciated﻿.

Comment: Programatically you can call `setIcon()` or in the layout designer you can choose a `drawable` for your image. However custom icons are not recommended.

Comment: But how to i set custom icons while connecting?

Comment: Just call `setIcon()` with the new `R.drawable` when you start connecting or when you press the Chromecast button in your app.

Comment: That doesn't seem to a good practice. Do you know whether CastCompanionLibarary have any option for this type of custom icons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this. The MediaRouter Button images are inside the android-support-v7-mediarouter library. So create a clone of it, add it to the projects and replace the existing mediarouter icons with the icons you want. Thats it.

Comment: android-support-v7-mediarouter library is, well, a library. It shouldn't be modified, especially when you consider calling `setIcon()` a bad practice.

Comment: I got this idea from Alid Nadaff who is the author of cast companion library.